# div positioning adjusting the height and width

Tags: html, css

I have one div positioned inside my popup and it contains the content to be displayed inside the popup .

Now , I am implementing it to have the property **overflow:auto** but I have one problem here.

Here is my div :

```
<div style="max-height:500px;max-width:500px;overflow:auto;">
<strong>Ad Tag for "sdk call test - greystripe"</strong><br><br>
<pre>
   &lt;sdkcall network="greystripe" appid="4ca44ca5-621d-4c13-b035-4c694868253e" slotname="interstitial" slottype="kGSAdSizeIPhoneFullScreen" /&gt;
</pre>
</div>
```

in case where my content  is small the horizontal scroll gets displayed immidiately after the content .

Given below are two such scenarios :

[image]

Again in case where the content is large :

[image]

I need to align the scroller at the very bottom of the outer div i.e. the popup-block div .
I have tried with height,width=100% but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your outer div a height 100% than your inner element should be able to use height 100%. Else if it is a fixed height you can set the height in pixels.

Comment: That is exactly what I have tried . I tried to set the height and width both to pixel value as they are set for my outer div but to no help.